# Teradata Current CPU utilization (Not User level and no History data)

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to run heavy extraction basically for migration of data from Teradata to some cloud warehouse and would want to check current CPU utilization (in percentage) of overall Teradata CPU and accordingly increase the extraction processes on it.

I know we have this type of information available in "dbc.resusagespma" but it looks like history data and not current, which we can see on Viewpoint.

Can we get such a run time information with the help of SQL in Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This info is returned by one of the PMPC-API funtions, [`syslib.MonitorPhysicalSummary`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/NdkMUPEon7RcxYO8pcolTQ/E~O7SbRc8awSu0oHfMleNw), of course, you need `Execute Function` rights:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (MonitorPhysicalSummary()) AS t
```

Comment: I have gone through the link for the documentation and column `AvgCPU` is what I need to refer if I want to check for current CPU utilized percentage. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Shawn: Yes, `AvgCPU` is the average CPU usage during the previous collection period. Viewpoint extracts similar info using PMPC-API, too.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, how old is the collection period?

Comment: The *collection rate* can be found/set in *Viewpoint - Monitored Systems - Setup - Monitor Rates*, usually data is refreshed every 30 or 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth , very useful info and it helped.

Comment: On the similar line, Can I extract current utilization of total IO percentage ? This function returns "AvgDiskIO", is it possible to calculate this in % ?

Comment: Have a look at `MonitorPhysicalResource`, info on node level, there's a `DiskUse` for each node

Comment: Ok, so to calculate for overall IO, we need to add these `DiskUse/number of nodes`, but looks like it will be good to get these stats for each node?